# How to do TDD using FDT with AS3 in MAC?

Tags: actionscript-3, tdd, fdt, asunit

I'd like to setup my environment to program doing Test Driven Development in ActionScript3. I tried using AsUnit but I don't know how to install it properly in MacOS.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new project in **FDT4** you are offered to create the new project with or without unit testing. If you choose 'with unit tesing' everything is setup for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

[as3unit](http://www.libspark.org/wiki/yossy/AS3Unit/en/index) is the way to go.  You can download the SWC version, then add it to your project build path.